# How to add github username to Zsh prompt?

Tags: zsh

I want to make sure when I'm in certain folders that I am also using the correct github username too. Here is my current prompt:

```
~/Documents/Github/TestOrg/testRepo branch
$
```

Code for that:

```
PROMPT='${NEWLINE}%F{yellow}%~%f %F{green}${vcs_info_msg_0_}${NEWLINE}%f$ '
```

I would love to have:

```
~/Documents/Github/TestOrg/testRepo githubusername@branch
$
```

Possible?

Comment: This is explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297578/how-to-update-prompt-on-directory-change), but make sure that you read through all comments, since the accepted solution currently contains an error.

Comment: Basically, your code has the problem that you never test the directory you are in. A first attempt would be to replace `${vcs_info_msg_0_}` by the invocation of a shell script or function, which prints on stdout the required information (based on the folder you are in).

Comment: The accepted solutions there does _not_ contain any bugs. It works in a clean Zsh environment as written.